# Property Observers In Kotlin (While Adding Elements to ArrayList)

Tags: kotlin

In Swift, there are *property observers* such as:

```
var foo: [String] = [String]() {
    didSet {
        someFunction()
    }
}
```

What happens here is whenever foo array is assigned a new value (e.g., foo = ["Ally", "Billy"] ) or a new element is appended or removed from array (e.g., foo.append("Willy") ); someFunction is run.

I write a similar logic in Kotlin such as:

```
var foo: ArrayList<String> by Delegates.observable(ArrayList<String>()){
    d, old, new ->
    someFunction()
}
```

So when I try to assign a new value to foo ArrayList (e.g., foo = ArrayListOf("Billy", Willy") ), someFunction is run.

The problem is when I add a new value to the array (or remove) by

```
foo.add("Ally")
```

then someFunction isn't called. Is there a way in Kotlin to call it? In other words, what I want to do is call someFunction whenever an element is added to or removed from foo array...

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `Delegates` you wrote works correctly, except that it observes the ArrayList object, not its content.

So `foo = listOf("foo")` will trigger `someFunction` but not `foo.add()`

What you can do though is

```
class observableList<Element>(
       private val observer : () -> Unit
    ):ArrayList<Element>() {

        override fun add(element: Element): Boolean = super.add(element).also { if (it) observer() }
        // etc, override the other method similarly
    }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Teovald, this is brilliant - it works perfectly!

Comment: A bit better style is to use composition instead of inheritance: `class ObservableList<Element>(private val base: MutableList<Element>, private val observer : () -> Unit): MutableList<Element> by base { override fun add(element: Element): Boolean = base.add(element).also { if (it) observer() } ...`